# Cast to ObjectId failed : Mean Stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

In the below code, I trying to update the user fields. This is my `editinfo.ts` page

```
userSpecificData:any = {_id:'-',name: '-', email: '-', username: '-', password: '-', phone: '-',education:'-',location:'-',title:'-',company:'-'}
     onEditFormSubmit(){
        const user = {
          _id:this.userSpecificData._id,
          name: this.userSpecificData.name,
          email: this.userSpecificData.email,
          username: this.userSpecificData.username,
          password: this.userSpecificData.password,
          phone:this.userSpecificData.phone,
          location:this.userSpecificData.location,
          title:this.userSpecificData.title,
          company:this.userSpecificData.company,
          education:this.userSpecificData.education
        }
    if (this.EditPageUserForm.dirty && this.EditPageUserForm.valid) {
    this.authService.updateUserData(user).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                if(data.success){
                this.flashMessage.show('You are now successfully registered, redirecting to Login page..', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 4000});
                //setTimeout(function(){
                  this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
                // },4000)

                console.log('sucess');
                } else {
                  this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 4000});
                // this.router.navigate(['/register']);
                console.log('faild');
                return false;
                }
              });
        }
      }
```

This is my `auth.service.ts` file

```
updateUserData(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log(headers,user);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/user/:id', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

The below code is from the routes file `users.js`

```
router.put('/user/:id', function(req, res){
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},
                       {
                      name: req.body.name,
                      email: req.body.email,
                      username: req.body.username,
                      phone:req.body.phone,
                      location:req.body.location,
                      title:req.body.title,
                      company:req.body.company,
                      education:req.body.education
               }, function(err, docs){
                if(err) res.json(err);
                else
                { 
                   console.log(docs);
                   res.redirect('/user/'+req.params.id);
                 }
             });
});
```

I'm not getting any error in my cmd but from in `console.log(data);` from `edit info.ts` I'm getting an error as

> {message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: ':id' }" at path
>   "_id" for model "User"", name: "CastError", stringValue: ""{ _id:
>   ':id' }"", kind: "ObjectId", value: {…}, …}

Comment: log your id in path with `console.log(req.params.id)` and check if it's a valid `ObjectId`

Comment: By the way `const user = {...this.userSpecificData}` might be a bit more elegant

Comment: try findByIdAndUpdate with a string as first argument. User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, {...})

Comment: When I'm using `console.log(req.params.id)` i"m getting the output as` :id`

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the string ':id' as the id of the user.

Thus this code

```
updateUserData(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log(headers,user);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/user/:id', user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

should become this

```
updateUserData(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    console.log(headers,user);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/users/user/' + user._id, user,{headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```